# finding the value of $f(2001) $ if.....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

if $f (\frac{x}{y}) =\frac{f(x)}{y} $ and $f(2000)=1$ ; then what's the value of $f(2001)$.
I tried hard but can't figured out anything. please help me, how can I proceed?

Comment: You should always post an attempt at your own solution here. Where exactly did you fail?

Comment: Do you know anything else about the function?  Is it continuous?  Is it defined only for integers?  Does it take values in the integers?  Without additional information, I don't think there is enough here to determine the value.

Comment: @Aaron Please also note that $f(1) =1 $.

Comment: Replacing $x$ with $xy$ suggests $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: I changed my question slightly. Now is it possible? #Aaron

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put $x=y \neq 0$ and we get
$$f(1)={f(x)\over x} \Rightarrow f(x)=f(1)x.$$
Since $f(2000)=1$, $f(1)=1/2000$. Therefore
$$f(2001)={2001\over2000}.$$